# Closing Windows SplashScreen when lost focus throws Win32Exception

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, splash-screen

In our application we open a splashscreen for the intial loading of the login screen, this logonscreen is shown async.
when we close the splashscreen sometimes we get following error:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled. Message="The operation completed successfully"

I figured out this has something to do with loosing focus and it's a known bug in .net 3.5.
However I did not find a solution to fix this in my code. And we are unable to upgrade the application to 4.0.

I allready tried: `Application.Current.MainWindow.Focus()` but this doens't work since i'm not on the correct thread due to the async call

I hope somebody had this problem before and can provide me a working fix for this bug.

This is the code and the splashscreen comes from `system.windows.dll`:

```
    Public Sub New(ByVal splashResourceName As String)

        logonSplash = New SplashScreen(splashResourceName)
        logonSplash.Show(False)

        InitializeComponent()
        GetAllInfo()
        DataContext = context

    End Sub

    Private Sub LoginDialog_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

        'Focus()
        If logonSplash IsNot Nothing Then
            logonSplash.Close(Nothing)
            logonSplash = Nothing
        End If

        txtPassword.Focus()

    End Sub
```